# Libreofice get column value, having number in cell

Tags: libreoffice

I have one cell with function:

```
=IF(J119<>J118,MATCH("signal",K120:K65001,0)+ROW(),"")
```

and for example it returns me 500.
I need to do now:

```
=MAX(F120,F500)
```

Of course first cell, returns me integer value.
How I can put into this MAX this value ?

I would like to do something like:

```
=MAX(F=ROW(), F=L119)
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the references as strings and then use [INDIRECT](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INDIRECT_function) to convert them to actual references.

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("F"&ROW()), INDIRECT("F"&L$119))
```